# dividing the image into four equal parts in JAI

Tags: java, imaging

please give me the coding for dividing the image into four parts from the center in Java Advanced Imaging..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about JAI, but here's the `BufferedImage` approach which you might use as an input for JAI. So maybe this works for your usecase

```
public static BufferedImage[] divide(BufferedImage source) {
  // for odd widths or heights, the last row or column will be ignored
  // fixing this behaviour is left as an exercise to the eager
  int height = source.getHeight() / 2;
  int width = source.getWidth() / 2;

  return new BufferedImage[] {
    source.getSubimage(0, 0, width, height), // top left
    source.getSubimage(width, 0, width, height), // top right
    source.getSubimage(0, height, width, height), // bottom left
    source.getSubimage(width, height, width, height) // bottom right
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting bit of *trompe-l'oeil* in Sun's [Java2D](http://www.java2html.com/examples/Java2D_demo/java2d/demos/Images/WarpImage.java.html)<sup>*</sup> demo using four [unequal parts](http://www.java2html.com/examples/Java2D_demo/java2d/demos/Images/WarpImage.java.html).

<sup>* See the lower, right quadrant of the `Images` tab.</sup>

Comment: +1 for make me wonder about what <b>trompe-l'oeil</b> means ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the example the width must come first than the height. That is:

```
source.getSubimage(0, 0,width, height ), // top left
source.getSubimage(width, 0, width, height), // top right
source.getSubimage(0, height, width, height), // bottom left
```